# How would I write a temporal forecast code in Microsoft excel

Tags: excel, time, prediction, analysis

An example, the time someone left home and the time someone called 9-1-1 and put these points in to predict ideally the time of incident on an excel format. I can put in a time in column a and column b but all it does is give me the half way point between the two. example column a says 12:00 and column b says 1:00 and the result would be 12:30. If I can get some thing more predictive using this approach, that is ideally what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used some of the standard functions in Excel to predict time based series.

We were looking at predicting data points for 1mis, 3mis and 6mis (mis = Months In Service).

We found that the forecast() function with some "fiddle" factors - sorry finely tuned polynomial assumptions - gave a reasonable prediction for our needs. We fed it steps of historical data to see the performance until it was suitable for what we needed.

Comment: how were the results; this seems ideally in the area I'm hoping to work towards.